# Bridge full wave rectifier more smooth signal

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

This is a full wave bridge rectifier:

[image]

The waveform of the full wave bridge rectifier is this :

[image]

But I want a more smooth signal which will remind less of an AC. If I put an inductor with a resistor instead of only a resistor will it work?

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* H. G Wells! I believe a better home for your question is the [electrical engineering stackexchange site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Also, [isn't it common to place a largish capacitor in parallel with the load resistor in order to reduce the ripple voltage?](https://www.physics-and-radio-electronics.com/electronic-devices-and-circuits/rectifier/bridgerectifierwithfilter.html)

Comment: I am asking about inductor not capacitor.

Comment: Whether you can place an inductor *usefully* in series depends on the impedance it sees. If the output impedance of the rectifier bridge is small compared to that of the load then an inductor will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I put an inductor with a resistor instead of only a resistor will
> it work?

While it's not entirely clear from your question, I believe you propose to place an inductor in *series* with the load $R_L$ (and, from your comment, you're not interested in using a shunt capacitor for filtering).

A series inductor (choke) would, in principle, act to reduce the ripple voltage across the load. In practice, however, it may not be a practical, e.g., the inductance required might be impractically large. Questions about how to calculate the required inductance should, I think, be asked at [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

You might find the following helpful:  [Rectifiers, Clippers, and Clampers](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323470335_Rectifiers_Clippers_and_Clampers)

[image]